# Strategies for optimizing views referencing views in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, view, query-optimization

Update:
Out of respect for your time I am adding indices in the tables that the subviews calling from. I will come back and edit this once I have improved as much as I can to minimize complexity and be more specific in my request for help. I can also delete and rewrite this post if that is preferred.

---

The bottleneck is the subview. The estimated plan shows most of the work is a Hash Match between the tables and the subview. [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r11_Se44d) to query plan

I understand that the predicates and the join columns should be indexed. What I'm not sure are ideal strategies for the subviews.

Should I:

1. Convert the subview to a table value function? I heard from an expert that this is an ideal solution but they didn't cover why. I don't know if the indexed columns from the subview carry in to the main view
2. Or do I need to convert the main view in to a table function too to take advantage of the indices?
3. Or maybe I'm way off and don't need to convert to table value function at all?

Main view:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 WITH (INDEX(IX_table1))
INNER JOIN table2 WITH (INDEX(IX_table2)) ON table1.field1 = table2.field1 
                                          AND table1.field2 = table2.field2
LEFT JOIN SubView WITH (nolock) ON table1.field1 = SubView1.field1
                                AND table1.field2 = SubView1.field2
                                AND table2.field3 = SubView1.field3
                                AND table2.field4 = SubView1.field4
WHERE table1.PredicateDate >= dynamicDate
  AND table1.field1 IN (3, 4)
  AND table1.field5 = 0
```

Comment: Just an observation - embedding nolocks and index hints in views is a really bad idea. What happens when someone drops that index? Sooner or later, they will, they always do. Presumably you're trying to work around the optimizer struggling to build an optimal plan!

Comment: You're way off by virtue of not knowing what exactly is the performance issue. It may be the case that a TVF will speed it up (unlikely unless window functions are involved). What you really need is to [edit] and add your table **and index** definitions, the definition of `SubView`, share a query plan via https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ , and explain: how `dynamicDate` gets into the query (variable, parameter, dynamic SQL), why you chose to force those indexes and `nolock`. Without this info, we can't help as we don't know where the issue might be nor what you have done to solve it.

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r11_Se44d

The view was not using the indices without the WITH hints. The dynamic date is a calculated variable. As for the NOLOCK, I don't have a good reasoning besides every code I inherited had it and nobody that reviewed my code criticized so I thought it was standard practice.

Comment: That's a rather different query than the one you have above. Your indexing clearly leaves room for improvement. **Please [edit] your question and add all the info I asked for**, along with the full query, and preferably an *actual* plan rather than an *estimated* plan, that would be great

Comment: SSMS, when you show the Actual Execution Plan, will recommend an index you can create to help your query run faster. Right-click in the query text box and choose "Show Actual Execution Plan", then run your query. And, we can help you much better if you [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) and give us more information. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the guidance. To respect your time, I did some more analysis and decided to optimize the subviews with more indices before involving you. I will come back and edit this once I have improved as much as I can to minimize complexity and be more specific in my request for help. 
I can also delete and rewrite this post if that is preferred. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is taking awhile to optimize the subviews due to dependencies outside my control. Were not able to delete the post so closing out this question for now.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies . . . put in the answer section instead of comment section.  But after trying to fix, it didn't matter . . . not enough posts to add a comment.

This is for tables on a Microsoft ERP system.  Microsoft has their default indexes on tables that shouldn't be changed or deleted. On any ERP upgrades, the indexes get recreated by Microsoft anyways.

The tables for most of the reporting are order history headers (8 million records) and lines (57 million records).  These tables get populated when an order is transferred to invoice or an invoice is posted.  For first situation, order goes to history table and an invoice is created in the open table.  The 2nd situation, an anvoice is moved to history table when the invoice is posted.  For these processes, the ERP system has a thick client (that hasn't changed much since 2010 or earlier).  The process is a rather long process with many tables that does not use an explicit SQL transaction.  If this process is interrupted, then a manual fix up is required for any tables that were not updated.

The READONLY/READUNCOMMITTED was initially used for large reporting against the live the database.  The Views that Vinh is using are used against a replication server that is now in place.  The READONLY is normally used against information that is in previous months/days so the current day changes are not a problem.  The large reports were slowing down the transfer and posting processes discussed in the previous paragraph. The posting process above currently takes about 1 hr to post 500 transactions, so it is good any time we can keep the process from slowing down.

Why a specific index is specified: The 57 million rows are divided into order types (SOPTYPE 2 (order), 3 (invoice), and 5 (backorder)).  Most of the Microsoft indexes use the SOPTYPE as the 1st field in the index.  So most of the queries end up using a index scan rather than an index seek.  In some cases, just specifying the index reduces the query time from 2 min to 5 sec.  When comparing the index scores, both indexes may be at 80% but SQL tends to choose the index with the SOPTYPE as the first index field.

We are probably one of the larger data users of the particular ERP system. I don't believe Microsoft has optimized for this data size.

I hope this information helps.